# ASP.NET 5 regex route endpoint for files and non-files

Tags: regex, asp.net-core, asp.net-routing

I have this possible urls:

```
mywebsite/a/b/c.txt
mywebsite/x/t
mywebsite/z
mywebsite/z/i.jpg
```

So when the url ends with a file, I need to return 404, otherwise I call the controller. To this I have

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{*.}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

And this how I'm trying to check for router files

```
// endpoints.MapGet("{file:regex(.(css|txt|js|jpg|png|ico|json)$)}", async context =>
// endpoints.MapGet(@"(.*\.)(jpe?g|css|txt|js|png|ico|json)$", async context =>
/* endpoints.MapGet(@"{file:regex((.*\.)(jpe?g|css|txt|js|png|ico|json)$)}", async context =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
}); */

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "File",
    // pattern: @"(.*\.)(jpe?g|css|txt|js|png|ico|json)$",
    // pattern: @"{controller:(.*\.)(jpe?g|css|txt|js|png|ico|json)$}",
    // pattern: "{ssn}",
    // constraints: new { ssn = @"(.*\.)(jpe?g|css|txt|js|png|ico|json)$" },
    pattern: @".*\.(css|js|gif|jpg)(/.)?",
    defaults: new { controller = "NotFound", action = "Index" });
```

The problem is that `https://localhost:5001/style.css` works, but `https://localhost:5001/z/style.css` it doesn't.

So what could I be missing here?

Comment: The wildcard `*` is a special char supported in `pattern`, I don't think that pattern means regex pattern. Many places in the source code seem to avoid using regex, if you read the source code you'll see that parsing the route is not just simply by writing a regex. Your best try may be to write code to repeat the `MapControllerRoute` (so you have multiple routes) somehow.

Comment: I see, any tips about how to write two MapControllerRoute? one for files and another one for anything else?

Comment: unfortunately your approach of using the catch-all wildcard cannot work for your purpose. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `catch-all` notation (expressed by `{*...}` or `{**...}`) to solve this issue. It does not support that way because the catch-all will match everything ***to the end*** of the path. The name following `*` is the route data key which can be used to get the captured value in your code later.

To solve this, you can use a middleware for this purpose. The route is mapped normally to some of your patterns. But later in the processing pipeline, we can examine the `Request.Path` to accordingly modify the `Request.Path (like URL rewriting), like this:

```
//inside Startup.Configure
app.Use((context, next) => {
            if(Regex.IsMatch(context.Request.Path, @".+(\.css|\.js|\.gif|\.jpg)$", 
                             RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
            {
                var linkGenerator = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<LinkGenerator>();
                var path = linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("Index", "NotFound") ?? "/NotFound";
                context.Request.Path = path;
            }
            return next();
        });
```

The above code must be placed ***before*** `app.UseStaticFiles`, otherwise the static files middleware will handle and short-circuit the requests first.

Note that `LinkGenerator.GetPathByAction` can return `null` if the controller or action does not exist. So in that case we fallback to the default conventional path of `/NotFound`.

Answer (score 0):

This regex

```
[^\/]+\w*\.\w*$
```

will return all URLs that end in file names. File names being defined as (word characters)(period)(word characters).

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/h4olRP/1).